# Openssl library for interacting with POP3 local server inconsistency while retrieving response

Tags: c, openssl, pop3

Im working with on pop3 clinet using openSSL library. However I run to this incosistency problem, when reading from BIO socket, 4 times out of 5 there is "\r\n.\r\n" at the end, indicating end of multi-line response from server. But sometimes only "\r\n" is being returned for some reason, and the rest ".\r\n" appears in the next BIO_read. Buffer is not overflowing, it is set to 1024 length and this happens even in 604 characters long response.

**Example:**

```
+OK 555 octets
Return-Path: test1@mail.local
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (mail.local [127.0.0.1])
    by LAPTOP-R30GIL79 with ESMTPA
    ; Wed, 20 Oct 2021 11:55:24 +0200
Message-ID: <dad24da8-dd91-62ed-3338-95fe46890c32@mail.local>
Date: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 11:55:24 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/91.2.0
Content-Language: sk
To: test1@mail.local
From: test1 <test1@mail.local>
Subject: testing
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Text testovacej spravy.

.
```

calling it exactly same after that results in:

```
+OK 555 octets
Return-Path: test1@mail.local
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (mail.local [127.0.0.1])
    by LAPTOP-R30GIL79 with ESMTPA
    ; Wed, 20 Oct 2021 11:55:24 +0200
Message-ID: <dad24da8-dd91-62ed-3338-95fe46890c32@mail.local>
Date: Wed, 20 Oct 2021 11:55:24 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/91.2.0
Content-Language: sk
To: test1@mail.local
From: test1 <test1@mail.local>
Subject: testing
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Text testovacej spravy.
\r\n
```

As you can see ".\r\n" is missing for some reason. Octets does match but it disappear somehow. There are no memory leaks. This is function Im using for reading BIO socket

```
int readBIO(){
    memset(buf, 0, strlen(buf));
    int x = BIO_read(bio,buf,BUFF_SIZE);
    if (x == 0 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Trying to read from closed connection.\n");
        freeAll();
        exit(1);
    }else if(x < 0){
        if (! BIO_should_retry(bio))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Reading from bio socked has failed.\n");
            freeAll();
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (checkResponse() != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Incorrect command / typo in command detected.\n Or wrong username / password has been entered.\n Server responded with -ERR.\n");
        freeAll();
        exit(1);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone might have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: tcp makes no guarantee that packet boundaries match message boundaries. It is up to the higher level protocol to keep reading in a loop until the complete message is received. The server does not know that you requested 1024 bytes. If it does 2 writes, they may or may not be sent in the same packet.

Comment: Oh I see, so there is no problem with some kind of overflowing but instead It's just server sending it like that? When I do this request using telnet program, it always answers as I would expect. So it may answer to telnet same way as it answers to my C program but telnet is actually handling it as being answered multiple times? I thought it will always fill up my buffer until there is no space left

Comment: @stark: and conversely one write may be sent in two (or more) segments. But probably more relevant here, assuming OpenSSL was used to do SSL/TLS=POP3S not just TCP=POP3, the **same is true for SSL/TLS**; see e.g. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-6.2.1 "Client
   message boundaries are not preserved"

Comment: Yeah, that’s why there *is* a \r\n.\r\n.  You are supposed to keep reading until you see that.

Comment: Imagine it did work like you surmised: it would keep reading until it filled the buffer: how would it know to stop?  Telnet, for example, just continuously read the socket and TTY buffers in a loop (probably using select/poll), and sending/printing the data to the other end. It does not know or care about packet boundaries,